# MFC Button not visible

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I have modHolder class object. It is used for modeless form.

```
class modHolder : public CWinThread
{
    DECLARE_DYNCREATE(modHolder)

protected:
    modHolder();          
    virtual ~modHolder();

public:
    CMainWindow * v1;
    virtual BOOL InitInstance();
    virtual int ExitInstance();

protected:
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};
```

That is created from main CWinApp object. CbSrvDlg dlg is main application window.

```
CbSrvApp theApp;
BOOL CbSrvApp::InitInstance()
{
...
    CWinApp::InitInstance();
...
    AfxBeginThread(RUNTIME_CLASS(modHolder));

        CbSrvDlg dlg;   // main dialog window

    m_pMainWnd = &dlg;
    INT_PTR nResponse = dlg.DoModal();
...
}
```

In modHolder I have frame with button inside of it:

```
class CMainWindow : public CFrameWnd
{
public:

    CMainWindow ();
        CButton m_wndPushButton;

protected:
    afx_msg LRESULT OnMyMessage1(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
    afx_msg  int OnCreate (LPCREATESTRUCT lpcs)   ;
    afx_msg void OnPaint ();
    afx_msg void OnPushButtonClicked ();
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP ()

};
```

Button created:

```
int CMainWindow::OnCreate (LPCREATESTRUCT lpcs)   
{
    if (CWnd::OnCreate (lpcs) == -1)   
        return -1;   

    CRect rectbutton(50,50,150,150); 

    m_wndPushButton.Create (_T ("Start"), WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE |  BS_PUSHBUTTON, rectbutton, this, IDC_PRINT);

return 0;  
}
```

Why "Start" button in most application start cases is not visible? To become it visible I need to move form (CMainWindow * v1) to another position.

Another strange application behavior is after application is started I see forms in taskbar but not on desktop, and looks application is hanged.

How to solve these problems?

Comment: Don't know what you mean by form here. If form means the CbSrvDlg then it is probably overlapping the CMainWindow as it is running in separate thread. Also, you may want to play with 50,50 position of the button to make it visible in your CMainWindow frame. Also, see if any other controls are not overlapping the button. In such cases the button would not be visible initially.

Comment: Your code is confusing.  Your CWinApp class implies you have a dialog based application, yet, you show code that also includes a frame window.  I'm not sure what your design is trying to accomplish.

Comment: I have added more comments to my problem description

Comment: I see no code that creates the CMainFrame window. I just see a dialog. How do you create the main frame in this thread?